# Full screen mode

Tags: wpf, xaml, fullscreen

Im trying to create a full screen mode, a normal mode and maximizeD mode.
It's something like Visual Studio has. When fullscreen is on, title bar hides. When maximized, title bar stays.

On my XAML has:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFullScreen}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized" />
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="mainDock"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

This code sets styles of my custom title bar when `IsFullScreen` is equal `true`, works fine. `x:Name="mainDock"` its the title bar only. Used to hide the title bar.

```
var window = (Window)((FrameworkElement)sender).TemplatedParent;
window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;

if (window.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal)
    window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
else
    window.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
```

This code is when I click on Maximize Button. Works fine.

The problem is when I maximize and after I try to activate full screen mode, only title bar hides and not cover the taskbar anymore. Its like if Windows Style didn't change anymore.

How can I do that? I need the three modes: full screen, maximized and normal. 
I tried to set MaxWidth, MaxHeight, Height, Width for example

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidthKey}}"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeightKey}}"/>
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I made this code

```
if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal || (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized && this.WindowStyle == WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow))
{
    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal; // if don't set dont work well
    this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;

    IsFullScreen = true;
}
else 
{
    this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
    this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
    this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;

    IsFullScreen = false;
}
```

But I think it's possible to create only with XAML